# reading xml facebook file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, facebook

I'm trying to read a xml file (from facebook) into my page.
I keep getting an error. Can't figure it out.

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim myURL As String = "http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=68310606562&format=rss20"

ds.ReadXml(myURL)
```

This throws an exception:

```
An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 12, position 53.
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `myURL` is your URL, not an XML filename.

Try first making a request to retrieve this XML content via WebClient's `DownloadString()` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) or similar method

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

var xmlData = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: html back. however, when I go to the link in the browser and view source I can see the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();            
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=68310606562&format=rss20");
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
string xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
doc.Load(xml);
```

You should be logged in to be able to retrieve the XML from Facebook.